# Use of case in MySQL LIKE query

Tags: mysql, case, sql-like

If I have a table with a column called `TITLE` which contains text of mixed case, e.g.

- `Vinashin to Receive Government Loans to Pay Workers`
- `German government concerned over rise in inflation`

Is it possible to perform an SQL LIKE query such as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE '%Government%'
```

But which would only return the first row and not the second?

MYSQL's `LIKE` seems to ignore case.

Comment: have you tried it and see what results you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> The following two statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC';
>         -> 0
> ```

So you can use `LIKE BINARY '%Government%'` to make a case-sensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
LIKE BINARY
```

instead of LIKE and it will match case sensitive.